# Pause, Start, Stop java

Tags: java, android

I have code that takes an image, extracts the text, and then reads it out. I want it to pause start and stop when the user hits the button. I have a stop and start feature, but when I hit stop, and it goes to continue, it restarts from the beginning.

Is there any way to track where the reader is on when it is reading the text to make sure that it continues from where it left off?

Recognizing Text Code:

```
private void recognizedTextFromImage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "recognizedTextFromImage: ");
    try {
        InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(this, imageUri);

        textRecognizer.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(text -> {
                    String recognizedText = text.getText();
                    recognizedTextEt.setText(recognizedText);

                    // Speak the recognized text
                    spokenText = text.getText();
                    recognizedTextEt.setText(spokenText);

                    speakRecognizedText();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed recognizing text due to " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "recognizedTextFromImage: ", e);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Preparing Image due to " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Stop, Start, Continue:

```
private void speakRecognizedText() {
    if (textToSpeech != null && textToSpeech.getEngines().size() > 0) {
        isSpeaking = false;
        startStopContinueSpeechBtn.setText("Start");

        if (lastPosition == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press 'Start' to start listening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String text = spokenText.substring(lastPosition);
        }
    }
}

private void stopSpeech() {
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        lastPosition = textToSpeech.stop();
        isSpeaking = false;
        isPaused = true;
        startStopContinueSpeechBtn.setText("Continue");
    }
}

private void continueSpeech() {
    if (textToSpeech != null && !isSpeaking) {
        isSpeaking = true;
        isPaused = false;
        startStopContinueSpeechBtn.setText("Stop");

        String text = spokenText.substring(lastPosition);
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, text);
    }
}


private void startSpeech() {
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        String text = recognizedTextEt.getText().toString();
        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            isSpeaking = true;
            isPaused = false;
            textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, text);
            startStopContinueSpeechBtn.setText("Stop");
        }
    }
}
```